# How to get the notes to play for a C Major with Tonal.js

Tags: javascript, tonal.js

I want to play the notes in C Major scale, like this:
`C4 D4 E4 F4 G4 A4 B4 C5`. Also for any major scale as well.

When I get a C Major scale with `Key.majorKey('C')` this is the output:

```
{
  "tonic": "C",
  "grades": [
    "I",
    "II",
    "III",
    "IV",
    "V",
    "VI",
    "VII"
  ],
  "intervals": [
    "1P",
    "2M",
    "3M",
    "4P",
    "5P",
    "6M",
    "7M"
  ],
  "scale": [
    "C",
    "D",
    "E",
    "F",
    "G",
    "A",
    "B"
  ],
  "chords": [
    "Cmaj7",
    "Dm7",
    "Em7",
    "Fmaj7",
    "G7",
    "Am7",
    "Bm7b5"
  ],
  "chordsHarmonicFunction": [
    "T",
    "SD",
    "T",
    "SD",
    "D",
    "T",
    "D"
  ],
  "chordScales": [
    "C major",
    "D dorian",
    "E phrygian",
    "F lydian",
    "G mixolydian",
    "A minor",
    "B locrian"
  ],
  "type": "major",
  "minorRelative": "A",
  "alteration": 0,
  "keySignature": "",
  "secondaryDominants": [
    "",
    "A7",
    "B7",
    "C7",
    "D7",
    "E7",
    ""
  ],
  "secondaryDominantsMinorRelative": [
    "",
    "Em7b5",
    "F#m7",
    "Gm7",
    "Am7",
    "Bm7b5",
    ""
  ],
  "substituteDominants": [
    "",
    "Eb7",
    "F7",
    "Gb7",
    "Ab7",
    "Bb7",
    ""
  ],
  "substituteDominantsMinorRelative": [
    "",
    "Em7",
    "Cm7",
    "Dbm7",
    "Am7",
    "Fm7",
    ""
  ]
}
```

This has a `scale` property which is close to what I want but missing the octaves.

How do I get the actual notes to play for a C Major Scale and any other major scale.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [docs](https://github.com/tonaljs/v2) say:

```
scale("major").map(transpose("C2")); // => ['C2', 'D2', 'E2', 'F2', 'G2', 'A2', 'B2']
```